# How do I render only some specific model-fields with an InvariantCulture, while the rest keeps using the users culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting, render, culture

I have a couple of hidden inputs on an asp.net mvc view. Their values contain objects of type `double`. I want them to be rendered with the `InvariantCulture` as they are used to be fed to an api (google maps) on the client. As it is now, they get rendered with a comma (,) as decimal separator, while the api expects a point (.) as decimal separator.

The nicest solution would be if I could specify a culture in the `DisplayFormat` data annotation attribute on the property on the model, but I don't think that is possible:

```
public class Position
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:G}, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture")]
    public double Latitude;
    ...
}
```

I can't also just set the `CurrentCulture` to `InvariantCulture` in my `Application_Start` method, as there are other values on the screen which have to be in the proper user culture.

So, is there a way to just temporarily change the current culture, right before I do an `Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Latitude)` for that specific property, and then reset it afterwards?

Or is there another better way of doing this? What is considered best practice concerning this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a template (Position.chtml) for a specific sub-object `Position` in my model like this:

```
@model Models.Position 
@{
    var latitude = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 "{0:G}", Model.Latitude);
    var longitude = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                  "{0:G}", Model.Longitude); 
} 
@Html.Hidden("Latitude", latitude) 
@Html.Hidden("Longitude", longitude) 
<p /> 
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/maps.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        attachMap($('#mapCanvas'), $('#Position_Latitude'), $('#Position_Longitude'), true);
    }) 
</script>
```

This way, I don't need to add any attributes to the model class.

I'm wondering though... is it good practice including javascript like this? I don't know of any other way to do it (except including it in the master page, which I don't want to do as I don't need it on all pages) without having to repeat myself. I'd like to keep this DRY...

Also (I might better ask a new question for this): As it is now, I have this template 2 times, once as an editor template, once as a display template. The only difference is that the last parameter to `attachMap` has to be `true` for the editor template and `false` for the display template. Is there an easy way to make this DRY?

Comment: Old post but I'll put my two cents anyway... First your scripts `~/Scripts/map.js` and the google maps script will be included each time this partial view will be rendered. Could be bad if you show more than one map in a given view. Also if you have more than one map you may want to customize the `mapCanvas` id so it is unique in the page. Third, you could use another partial view that is called by both editor and display template, and receive info for the `attachMap` boolean parameters.

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this would be to write a custom editor template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/InvariantDouble.cshtml`:

```
@{
    object modelValue = string.Format(
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString, 
        ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model
    );
}
@Html.TextBox("", modelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
```

and then on your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:G}")]
[UIHint("InvariantDouble")]
public double Latitude;
```

and finally on your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Latitude)
```

or if you wanted all doubles in your application to behave like this use the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Double.cshtml` without any `UIHint`.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I also have a `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]` attribute on the property?

Comment: @fretje, then override `HiddenInput.cshtml`. Brad Wilson covers the default templates at this blog post: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

Comment: I did it a little bit different... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300525/how-do-i-render-only-some-specific-model-fields-with-an-invariantculture-while-t/5309154#5309154).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForInvariant<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var id = string.Format("{0}", metadata.PropertyName);
        var compile = expression.Compile();
        string value = Convert.ToString(compile(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var hidden = htmlHelper.Hidden(id, value).ToHtmlString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(hidden);
    }
```